# Does there exist such an $\ell^2$ sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x = (x_k) \in \ell^2$. Can we find $x \in \ell^2$ such that $\inf_{k \neq j}|x_k-x_j| > 0$?

I have been trying to come up with some examples, but have not had much luck.
Of course we cannot have any elements in our sequence repeat themselves.
I am having trouble coming up with some examples since we have to make sure our sequence is always at some distance from its elements but also not too big so that we still converge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(x_k)$ is $\ell^2$, then it converges to zero and :
$$\inf_{k\neq j}|x_k-x_j|\leq \inf_{n\in\mathbb N} |x_{n+1}-x_n|  = 0$$
so
$$\inf_{k\neq j} |x_k-x_i|=0$$